# Webcam driver settings?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv, webcam

I'm working on a C++ application that uses OpenCV/ffmpeg to capture video frames from my built-in webcam (Studio XPS 13). This application is really sensitive to those auto light adjustments that the webcam driver does.... is there any way I can change this behavior? Either via some webcam driver settings app, or in code (you may suggest a different library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure what the most general way to do this is, but I know that the module for my webcam (ov511) has options to tweak all these settings... try running `modinfo` for the kernel module.

Comment: Can you be a little more detailed? I don't know how to use `modinfo`. What args do I need to pass to it?

Comment: You'll need to determine what kernel module is being used for your webcam.  You can examine the tail of `dmesg` after connecting it, as well as looking at what modules are loaded with `lsmod`.  Then you just run `modinfo foo` where foo is the module name (ov511 in my case).